# Can I Play an audio while recording a video on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, audio, video, avfoundation

I'm trying to record a video while the iPhone playback an audio track.
as far as i tried, whenever I simulataniously record and play - the camera get stuck.
I went over the [AVFoundation PG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html) But I could not find a specific answer.

Is it a matter of digging into this framework?

Is it a matter of threading and multitasking?

thanks

Comment: hey do you have a sample code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I record both audio and video while playing audio. However, in my setup I am using CoreAudio for audio and AVFoundation for video. You may want to setup the audio session to handle recording and playback. e.g.

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL,  NULL, self);

UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(audioCategory), &audioCategory);
AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
```